# Outlook 2003 / 2007 Word Wrap Behavior Differences

Tags: email, microsoft-office, microsoft-outlook-2007, html, microsoft-outlook-2003

I have an email that requires the use text inside of HTML PRE tags in the message source.  When viewing this message, I've noticed that Outlook 2003 will NOT word wrap this text but Outlook 2007 will.

What is the correct and expected behavior?  Is there a way to force Outlook 2003 to wordwrap the text even though it's inside a PRE tag?

Thanks,

M

Answer (score 0):

Outlook 2007 uses a new HTML renderer. Consequently, there is no easy way to go back to the old behavior short of sticking with Outlook 2003.